# how to view how many times a person downloaded an app

Tags: applications

I noticed that the iTunes purchase history only shows the first time you downloaded an app, and doesn't show every time, it was redownloaded. Is there a way to view how many times, or the most recent time an app was redownloaded in my account?

Answer (score 1):

You can actually see your purchase history inside iTunes. There is a link called **'See All'**, which will let you see all purchases.

Refer this from [Apple](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204088)